# Pandas resample dataFrame for 30 minutes interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following data structure, which I am using to create pandas DataFrame

```
[
    {
        "datetime":"2021-05-21 00:00:00",
        "value":5
    },
    {
        "datetime":"2021-05-22 00:00:00",
        "value":6
    }
]
```

- The "datetime" could be in hours / minutes / days/ months / years

I would like to resample the above data to 30 minutes interval and fill values using mean.
when I use code below, it does convert pandas dataframe to 30 minutes interval but mean is not calculated, instead i get NaN values,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["datetime"] = df["datetime"].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df.set_index("datetime")
df.resample("30min").mean()
```

I would like to transform the input data to this format:

```
    [
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-21 00:00:00",
            "value":0.104166667
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-21 00:30:00",
            "value":0.104166667
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-21 01:00:00",
            "value":0.104166667
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-21 01:30:00",
            "value":0.104166667
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-21 02:00:00",
            "value":0.104166667
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-21 02:30:00",
            "value":0.104166667
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-21 03:00:00",
            "value":0.104166667
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-21 03:30:00",
            "value":0.104166667
        },
        ...
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-22 00:00:00",
            "value":0.125
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-22 00:30:00",
            "value":0.125
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-22 01:00:00",
            "value":0.125
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-22 01:30:00",
            "value":0.125
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-22 02:00:00",
            "value":0.125
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-22 02:30:00",
            "value":0.125
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-22 03:00:00",
            "value":0.125
        },
        {
            "datetime":"2021-05-22 03:30:00",
            "value":0.125
        },
    ]
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: You could try `df.resample("30min").fillna('ffill')`, then divide by 48.

Comment: But if interval is for a "month" then division with 48 would be incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
​
tmp = df.set_index("datetime")
​
dt_idx = pd.date_range(tmp.index.min(),
                       tmp.index.max() + pd.DateOffset(hours=23), freq="30min")
​
out = tmp.reindex(dt_idx, fill_value=0)
​
out = (out.groupby(out.index.date).transform("mean")
           .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(x.index.astype(str)))
           .reset_index(names="datetime").to_dict("records")
)
​
```

Output :

```
print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))

[
    {
        "datetime": "2021-05-21 00:00:00",
        "value": 0.10416666666666667
    },
    {
        "datetime": "2021-05-21 00:30:00",
        "value": 0.10416666666666667
    },
    {
        "datetime": "2021-05-21 01:00:00",
        "value": 0.10416666666666667
    },

    ...

    {
        "datetime": "2021-05-22 22:00:00",
        "value": 0.1276595744680851
    },
    {
        "datetime": "2021-05-22 22:30:00",
        "value": 0.1276595744680851
    },
    {
        "datetime": "2021-05-22 23:00:00",
        "value": 0.1276595744680851
    }
]
```

Comment: Oh thank you so very much, this worked like a charm, only thing I added is "minutes=30" in pd.DateOffset. then it worked perfectly, so the last date also has time until 23:30..

Answer (score 0):

Well, not the prettiest solution but you can use below code as well.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["datetime"] = df["datetime"].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='30min'))["value"].mean().reset_index().fillna(0)[:-1]
df["value"] = np.mean(df["value"])
```

Output is shown below.

```
              datetime     value
0  2021-05-21 00:00:00  0.104167
1  2021-05-21 00:30:00  0.104167
2  2021-05-21 01:00:00  0.104167
3  2021-05-21 01:30:00  0.104167
4  2021-05-21 02:00:00  0.104167
5  2021-05-21 02:30:00  0.104167
6  2021-05-21 03:00:00  0.104167
7  2021-05-21 03:30:00  0.104167
8  2021-05-21 04:00:00  0.104167
9  2021-05-21 04:30:00  0.104167
10 2021-05-21 05:00:00  0.104167
11 2021-05-21 05:30:00  0.104167
12 2021-05-21 06:00:00  0.104167
13 2021-05-21 06:30:00  0.104167
14 2021-05-21 07:00:00  0.104167
15 2021-05-21 07:30:00  0.104167
16 2021-05-21 08:00:00  0.104167
17 2021-05-21 08:30:00  0.104167
18 2021-05-21 09:00:00  0.104167
19 2021-05-21 09:30:00  0.104167
20 2021-05-21 10:00:00  0.104167
21 2021-05-21 10:30:00  0.104167
22 2021-05-21 11:00:00  0.104167
23 2021-05-21 11:30:00  0.104167
24 2021-05-21 12:00:00  0.104167
25 2021-05-21 12:30:00  0.104167
26 2021-05-21 13:00:00  0.104167
27 2021-05-21 13:30:00  0.104167
28 2021-05-21 14:00:00  0.104167
29 2021-05-21 14:30:00  0.104167
30 2021-05-21 15:00:00  0.104167
31 2021-05-21 15:30:00  0.104167
32 2021-05-21 16:00:00  0.104167
33 2021-05-21 16:30:00  0.104167
34 2021-05-21 17:00:00  0.104167
35 2021-05-21 17:30:00  0.104167
36 2021-05-21 18:00:00  0.104167
37 2021-05-21 18:30:00  0.104167
38 2021-05-21 19:00:00  0.104167
39 2021-05-21 19:30:00  0.104167
40 2021-05-21 20:00:00  0.104167
41 2021-05-21 20:30:00  0.104167
42 2021-05-21 21:00:00  0.104167
43 2021-05-21 21:30:00  0.104167
44 2021-05-21 22:00:00  0.104167
45 2021-05-21 22:30:00  0.104167
46 2021-05-21 23:00:00  0.104167
47 2021-05-21 23:30:00  0.104167
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, well this works nicely but the only issue I see that it gives back data for date 1 date (21), I solved this issue by removing [:-1], But then mean is for entire data frame, it is not grouped by date!

Sorry I think I did write the output data correctly in the answer, but it should include all the dates that are in input data

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect this!

Answer (score 0):

More general approach

I.e. if you don't know frequency of data points, that you receive as input (it could be once a day / 12 hours / 2 hours / 1.5 hour / 45min).

```py
import json
import pandas
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

# Question
data = [
    {
        "datetime":"2021-05-21 00:00:00",
        "value":5
    },
    {
        "datetime":"2021-05-22 00:00:00",
        "value":6
    }
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
df = df.set_index(df.datetime)

# Answer
period = df[-1:].index - df[-2:-1].index # get the difference of last two rows in df
offset = to_offset(period.to_series()[0]) # convert to offset for groupby later

json.dumps(
    pd.concat([
        df,
        df[-1:].set_index(df[-1:].index.shift(1, freq=offset)) # it is a copy of last row
    ]) # it is a trick, I add one more row to df with respect of offset
    .resample('30min').mean().fillna(0) # get resample with a "tail" and 0s
    .resample(offset).mean() # get mean value per original offset
    .resample('30min').ffill() # resamle and fill with a mean value
    .reset_index().to_dict('records') # convert to a dict
    [:-1], # cut off last row
    default=str # it will convert datetime to str for me
)
```